# Unable to query BigQuery data in Apache Superset - queries executed successfully at BigQuery but results not returned at Superset

Tags: python, flask, google-bigquery, sqlalchemy, apache-superset

Unable to query BigQuery data. I could see the executed queries at the BigQuery project history. Even simple SQL statements are not returning results at Superset.

**How to reproduce the error:**

- Installed latest version of Apache Superset (2.1) & tried with older previous version of Superset and Python (3.8)
- Installed SQLAlchemy BigQuery connector
- Created database connection successfully and able to see the datasets and tables
- Creating Dataset / creating charts / running simple SQL statements at SQL lab produce Gateway
  TimeOut error.

**Expected results**

Result set at sql lab / data returning at the superset for creating charts.

**Actual results**

Gateway Timeout Error - queries running forever and then timeout after the timeout threshold.

**Screenshots**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Environment**

```
Browser: Tested with Google Chrome, Edge, Safari
superset version: Superset 2.1.0 / Tested with Superset 2.0
python version: Python 3.10 / Tested with Python 3.8
bigquery connector: sqlalchemy-bigquery 1.6.1 / Tested with Pybigquery
OS version: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Hosted on: GCP VM
```

**Additional context**

The VM hosted on GCP Compute Engine and verified the access to BigQuery - APIs access is already enabled and able to query data using the same connector (sqlalchemy-bigquery).

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from pprint import pprint

bigquery_uri = f'bigquery://{project}/{table}'

engine = create_engine(
    bigquery_uri,
)

query = f'SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(partition) = "2023-05-05" LIMIT 10;'
rows = engine.execute(query).fetchall()

rows = [dict(row) for row in rows]

pprint(rows)
```

Does not look like connectivity issue as I could see the datasets and tables listed for the database and once queries are executed, I could see the same successfully executed queries at the BigQuery.

[image]

Please let me know if you require any additional information. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.